# Android device displaying black screen while web requests

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm facing with a black screen problem. While web request operation, some devices(some of them freeze for a second and than everything is normal)  displays black screen for a while and nothing happens.

I use Retrofit:2.0.0-beta4, asynchronous web requests. So, my web requests does not work on the main thread.

I tried giving timeout manually via okhhttp client. But it didn't work i faced with the same results.

This is my retrofit method :

```
public Retrofit getRetrofit(Context context){
    client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(SingletonLikeApp.getInstance().getConfig(context).apiBaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    return client;
}
```

And the below enqueue method requests asynchronously

```
 SpikaOSRetroApiInterface retroApiInterface = getRetrofit(context).create(SpikaOSRetroApiInterface.class);
        Call<GetSectorModel> call = retroApiInterface.getSectorList(SingletonLikeApp.getInstance().getSharedPreferences(context).getToken());
        call.enqueue(new CustomResponse<GetSectorModel>(context, true, false)  {

            @Override
            public void onCustomSuccess(Call<GetSectorModel> call, Response<GetSectorModel> response) {

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCustomFailed(Call<GetSectorModel> call, Response<GetSectorModel> response) {


        });
    }
```

This is interface of related method.

```
@POST(Const.Api.GET_SECTOR_LIST)
Call<GetSectorModel> getSectorList(@Header(Const.Params.ACCESS_TOKEN) String token);
```

These are the logs of the device which freeze for 4 secs for a single web request[image]

And the black screen problem. After login, there are 4 web requests running, and the device displays approximately 30 secs black screen.

[image]

Thanks...

Comment: Are you doing some process in **SingletonLikeApp.getInstance().getConfig(context)** this piece of code..?

Comment: I don't think so. only simple url configurations.